# Rails and ActiveAdmin before_destroy Isn't Stopping the Destroy Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

**Using Rails 4.2.4 and ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre4.**

From the ActiveAdmin User dashboard, I need to check whether or not a user has permission to delete another user when they click the default `Delete` link AA provides. This is what I currently have in `app/admin/user.rb`:

```
  controller do

    before_destroy :check_if_user_can_destroy

    def check_if_user_can_destroy(resource)
      if current_user == resource || current_user.level < resource.level
        puts "plz stop"
        return false
      end
    end

  end
```

The text "plz stop" gets outputted to the console when I delete someone I shouldn't be able to, but the delete action happens anyways and the user gets zapped.

From what I've read, returning `false` in a `before` action should stop the subsequent action from running, is that not correct?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I changed things around and wound up with this, which seems to work...but I don't trust it yet for some reason. Am I good? Any glaring "gotchas" in doing this?

Still in `app/admin/user.rb`, of course:

```
  controller do

    def destroy
      if current_user == resource || current_user.level < resource.level
        redirect_to "/admin/users"
      else
        resource.destroy
      end
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_destroy` can't abort a destroy, it only runs code before the destroying. It is for example to send a notice mail or something like that.

Your overwrite is safe for work!

But what you do in the overwrite is much more better placed in a Authentification System (for example [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)). [Here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md) you find how to use them in ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, additional reading, and the sanity check you've given me! I thought I was taking crazy pills, but this makes way more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You can abort with:

- Rails 5: `throw :abort`
- Rails 4: `return false`

in before_destroy hook.

Note that you should place abort hook before any manipulating hooks e.g. `dependent: :destroy`.